# How to kill a specific x11rdp session

Tags: 12.04, xrdp, gnome-session, x11rdp

I am using x11rdp with xrdp v0.6.0 in ubuntu 12.04

The problem that when I connect remotely from home to office my session is stuck!

When I get back to work I can't open applications that are already run in the x11rdp session. e.g. Firefox, empathy...

I have to close them then I can open the needed app again.

I know I can `pkill -u user` but it seems non-professional

I tried `sudo service xrdp restart` (or stop then start). It doesn't close current sessions.

**Is there is any xrdp session manager like in windows server or can I kill only my user's session?**

Comment: similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/727057/how-to-find-disconnected-xrdp-sessions

Answer (score 5):

Using the command below:

```
ps u -u "$USER" | awk '/xrdp/ && ! /awk / {system("kill "$2)}'
```

- Replace `$USER` with another user name if the process is running with a different user than you
- Replace `xrdp` with your process name

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep <user> | grep -i x11rdp
```

will give you the process id in the second column of the line that's not your grep.

You can then

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Answer (score -1):

To list all the rdp sessions with theire respective pid and port numbers:

```
{ echo "user pid Xdisplay port"; { ps -ef | \
  awk '/Xvnc :[[:digit:]]+/ {print $1,$2,$9}' | while read tu tpid tvnc; \
  do sudo netstat -tlpn | awk -v "tpid=${tpid}" '$0 ~ tpid {print $4;}' | \
  sed -r -e 's/^.*://;' -e "s/^/${tu} ${tpid} ${tvnc} /;" ; done ; } | \ 
  sort -k3 ; } | column -c4 -t
```

you can then kill the specific process id (pid):

`$ kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: The question is about RDP not VNC. In any case, the command only returns `: command not found` on my system.